# use cast in SQL case statement

Tags: sql, casting, case

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN column1 = 43 THEN CAST('abcde' as varchar(30))  
       WHEN column1 = 44 THEN CAST('fghij' as varchar(30))
       ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS value
```

Is the above case and cast statement correct? I need to convert the `int` to a  `varchar`. `column1` is a value that comes from another table.

Question 2: I have two values coming from two different tables (table1 and table2) and they need to go to the final table data type varchar

value 1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(c.table1 * 100 AS DECIMAL(5,2))) + ' %' AS value1

value 2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.table2,101) AS value2

c.table1 is decimal coming from table1 
c.table2 is int coming from table2 and both need to be varchar at the final table

how do I combine both statements so that it can show up in the final table, its not an OR its an AND. 
result set:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: That first `case` _expression_ makes no sense, since 43 = 43 always is TRUE.

Comment: And the cast doesn't make sense either as `'abcde'` is already a varchar literal

Comment: it was just an example 43 = 43, I know it will always be true